# gfortran optimizer prevents an access violation

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following program tries to do a common mistake: modify a function argument,
whereas it is passed initially as a constant. Thus, usually, the constant is stored
in a read-only section in object code, and at run time one gets an access violation.

It's exactly what happens with gfortran, with optimization -O0 or -O1 (gfortran 4.8.1 on Windows).
But it disappears with -O2, and the second PRINT shows the value 100, like the first.

By inspection of the assembly output, I can see that in the -O1 case, the function F is optimized out, but the computations are still done in the code of A, and storing 117 causes a crash. With -O2, no computation is done, the result (201) is included in the assembly output as a constant, and the value 117 is never stored.

```
program bob
    implicit none
    call a(100)
contains
    subroutine a(n)
        integer :: n
        print *, "In A:", f(n), n
        print *, n
    end subroutine
    function f(n)
        integer :: n, f
        f = 2*n + 1
        n = 117
    end function
end program
```

Is this behaviour accepted by the standard? Is this a bug?
My first thought was that maybe it's a bug of the optimizer (it does not do something that would have indeed an effect, since the modified value is printed afterwards). But I'm aware that usually, an undefined behaviour in the standard can have *any* consequence when actually run.

If I replace the constant 100 in the call, with a variable previously initialized to 100, the compiler produces the expected result (the second PRINT gives me 117, with any optimization level).

So, maybe the optimizer is very clever, in the "constant" case: since the code would crash, the print woud not happen, so the value is not needed, so optmized out, and finally the program won't crash. But I still find it a bit puzzling.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get segfaults at the `n=117` line with flags `O1`, `O2`, and `O3` when using gfortran 4.6.3 and ifort 13.1.3

Comment: The same results for me. FWIW Oracle `sunf90 -fast` prints `201 117 117`

Comment: Note that this can be specific to the fact that you use internal procedures. They are probably inlined.

Comment: F is inlined, not A. But you're right, when the functions are not internal, I always get a segfault too. It's quite natural: when these functions are internal, only the main program can call them, so the compiler "knows" the only call is done with a constant, and it can somehow optimize out the n=117. When they are not internal, the program could be linked with other functions calling these, with true variable arguments.

Comment: @Kyle. Then it was introduced in a later version. I use exactly **[this](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingwbuilds/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/32-bit/threads-win32/dwarf/x32-4.8.1-release-win32-dwarf-rev5.7z)** one.

Comment: On linux, with gfortran 4.8.1 (20130725), I can reprocuce your finding. Looks like a bug in the optimization.

Comment: Funnily, if I add a `print *, "blabla"` just before `call a(100)`, the program don't crash anymore when compiled with -O1. It still crashes with -O0. I also tried separately, but together with -O1, every option [said to be implied by -O2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), and no one seems to cause the "bug" alone (the program crashes with all tries, as with -O1 alone).

Comment: by the way, FYI, I used gfotran 4.8.1 to compile other programs with disastrous results, I wouldn't use it yet for production :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in the constants propagation module of the GCC optimiser. It is enabled by default for any optimisation level greater than `-O1` and could be disabled by passing `-fno-ipa-cp`.

This example only serves to illustrate the importance of giving each dummy argument the correct `INTENT` attribute. When `n` is marked as `INTENT(INOUT)` in `a`, the compiler gives an error, no matter what the optimisation level.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be the option causing the problem, nice to know where it comes from.

Comment: The IPA-CP seems to be causing lots of trouble in many corner cases. If you look in GCC's Bugzilla, the first question is always "Does it work with `-fno-ipa-cp`?"

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of the erroneous program is consistent with what the standard requires.

The standard doesn't require the compiler to diagnose this particular error (it is not a violation of the numbered syntax rules or numbered constraints).  Beyond that, if a program is in error in this way, then the standard doesn't impose any requirements on the Fortran processor.

It does not reveal a bug in the compiler.  Any behaviour is valid, including things like the compiler beating you over the head with a stick.

Perhaps you should have stated your INTENT.

Comment: It's more or less the answer I expected. Anyway, it's a bit strange that the compiler produces a crashing program depending on the optimization level, and even on the presence of a simple PRINT statement. Even though the compiler is allowed to do that according to the standard (which I had already understood by myself, I know I can possibly(!) declare WW3 with a bad Fortran program), it's a bit annoying, and maybe, just maybe, a compiler bug. I'm not absolutely sure that GCC mainteners intended this.

Comment: Btw, I know what I should have stated. It was just a test, as I would not write this program for production use (or for any use whatsoever, beyond testing). I like to know the limits of my compiler, and maybe I've just touched one.

Comment: Note your code is non-conforming even if the actual argument to a was not a constant.

Comment: Maybe I'm still a bit asleep, I can't see. Why is it non conforming?

Comment: See F2008 7.1.4p1 - "If a function reference causes definition ... of an actual argument of the function, that argument ... shall not appear elsewhere in the same statement."

Comment: Oh, yes, this one (was already in F77, btw). I also wanted to test evaluation order :-)

Comment: And even [F66](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1966-Fortran66.pdf), section 6: "The evaluation of functions appearing in an expression may not validly alter the value of any other element within the expressions, assignment statement, or CALL statement in which the function reference appears." Quite an old ban :-)